# Create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame from existing column names

Tags: python, pandas

I want to deconstruct a pandas DataFrame, using column headers as a new data-column and create a list with all combinations of the row index and columns.  Easier to show than explain:

```
index_col = ["store1", "store2", "store3"]
cols = ["January", "February", "March"]
values = [[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index_col, columns=cols)
```

From this DataFrame I wish to get the following list:

```
[['store1', 'January', 2],
 ['store1', 'February', 3],
 ['store1', 'March', 4],
 ['store2', 'January', 5],
 ['store2', 'February', 6],
 ['store2', 'March', 7],
 ['store3', 'January', 8],
 ['store3', 'February', 9],
 ['store3', 'March', 10]]
```

Is there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df.unstack().swaplevel().reset_index().values.tolist()
#OR
df.reset_index().melt(id_vars="index").values.tolist()
# [['store1', 'January', 2],
#  ['store2', 'January', 5],
#  ['store3', 'January', 8],
#  ['store1', 'February', 3],
#  ['store2', 'February', 6],
#  ['store3', 'February', 9],
#  ['store1', 'March', 4],
#  ['store2', 'March', 7],
#  ['store3', 'March', 10]]
```

With following, the order of elements will match the output in the question.

```
df.transpose().unstack().reset_index().values.tolist()
# [['store1', 'January', 2],
#  ['store1', 'February', 3],
#  ['store1', 'March', 4],
#  ['store2', 'January', 5],
#  ['store2', 'February', 6],
#  ['store2', 'March', 7],
#  ['store3', 'January', 8],
#  ['store3', 'February', 9],
#  ['store3', 'March', 10]]
```

Comment: This is definitely the best (although mine is good, this is more concise and even more "true Pandas-style").

Comment: Does it need to be in the same order?

Comment: @LarrytheLlama, you could do `df.unstack().swaplevel().reset_index().sort_values("level_0").values.tolist()` if the order is important

Answer (score 6):

True Pandas-style:

```py
lst = [[*k, v] for k, v in df.unstack().swaplevel().to_dict().items()]
```

Comment: Beautiful use of nest list comprehensions and multiple pandas methods!

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer stacking over unstacking then swapping the levels:

```
>>> df.stack().reset_index().to_numpy()
array([['store1', 'January', 2],
       ['store1', 'February', 3],
       ['store1', 'March', 4],
       ['store2', 'January', 5],
       ['store2', 'February', 6],
       ['store2', 'March', 7],
       ['store3', 'January', 8],
       ['store3', 'February', 9],
       ['store3', 'March', 10]], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Or with `melt` and `ignore_index=False`:

```
>>> df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index().to_numpy()
array([['store1', 'January', 2],
       ['store2', 'January', 5],
       ['store3', 'January', 8],
       ['store1', 'February', 3],
       ['store2', 'February', 6],
       ['store3', 'February', 9],
       ['store1', 'March', 4],
       ['store2', 'March', 7],
       ['store3', 'March', 10]], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Comment: This is a good one too!

Answer (score 1):

The structure that you want your data in is very messy, so this is probably the best method given the data you want.

```
# Results
res = []

# Nested loop: first for length of index col, then next for cols
for i in range(len(index_col)):
    for j in range(len(cols)):
        # Format of data
        res.append([index_col[i], cols[j], values[i][j]])

# Return results
print(res)
return res
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over dataframe items using

```
data = []

for col, row in df.items():
    for ind, val in row.reset_index().values:
        data.append([ind, col, val])

data
```

You could avoid the second loop for sacrificing the order you requested the output in as it is a bit of a full breakdown of how the structure started.

Answer (score 1):

```py
temp = df.stack()

[[*ent, val] for ent, val in zip(temp.index, temp)]

[['store1', 'January', 2],
 ['store1', 'February', 3],
 ['store1', 'March', 4],
 ['store2', 'January', 5],
 ['store2', 'February', 6],
 ['store2', 'March', 7],
 ['store3', 'January', 8],
 ['store3', 'February', 9],
 ['store3', 'March', 10]]
```